# Can I create an object in one function and constructing in another?

Tags: c#, .net

So I got an assignment [college student] to create a program that runs a garage. I have a class for every car type [FuelMotorcycle, ElectricMotorcycle, FuelCar, ElectricCar, etc.], each car type has its own constructor and they all differ from one another.
One of the assignment requirements is to "place the code that creates car objects [new], and this code alone, in a class on the logical part of the program, this code part cannot turn to the user directly or indirectly" (translated).
So the way I see it, I have a class, let's say "EmptyCarCreator" , that will have methods such as:

```
public static FuelMotorcycle CreateNewFuelMotorcycle()
        {
            FuelMotorcycle EmptyFuelMotorcycle;
            return EmptyFuelMotorcycle;
        }
```

obviously this won't compile, and even if it did, I couldn't use the "FuelMotorcycle" class constructor after I get it returned.
I need the user to input the elements for the constructor.
So, is there any other way to do this? I feel like I am missing something very basic here.
Please excuse any English errors, hope my question was clear.

Comment: Look up the Factory pattern.

Comment: When we separate a class from its construction that's the Builder Pattern.

Comment: `FuelMotorcycle EmptyFuelMotorcycle = new FuelMotorcycle();` ?

Comment: @David This way I can't use the constructor later. I need the user to insert information that I'll later use in the constructor, such as car color

Comment: @Gilzy: What does "use the constructor later" even mean?  You're either *constructing* the object here or you aren't.  (And, if you aren't, what exactly are you doing?)  Can't the `color` value be passed to `CreateNewFuelMotorcycle(Color color)`, which would in turn pass it to the constructor?

Comment: @David If I'll first ask the user what color the car is, and then pass this value to the function, wouldn't that violate the "this code part cannot turn to the user directly or indirectly" rule?

Comment: @Gilzy: That stated requirement doesn't even make sense to me.  What does "turn to the user" mean?  This factory method would simply be requiring that any consuming code supply it with whatever information is required to construct the object.  It doesn't care where that information came from, and it's not interacting with the user in any way.  (In fact, this code would belong in the domain logic and not in the application layer at all, so it *can't* interact with the UI.)  If the requirement is to construct an object without the information needed to construct an object, then that can't work.

Comment: Maybe there is translation issue here.
I am guessing that there is some confusion between "creating" and "instantiating"?

Answer (score -1):

You would need something like this:

```
public static class EmptyCarCreator
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
FuelMotorcycle myVehicle = EmptyCarCreator.Create<FuelMotorcycle>();
```

This will create a new class through the parameterless constructor.

There are other options that might be able to handle parameters a little better like this:

```
public static class EmptyCarCreator
{
    public static object Create(Type type)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

To use this you would have to cast this returned object.

```
FuelMotorcycle myVehicle = (FuelMotorcycle)EmptyCarCreator.Create(typeof(FuelMotorcycle));
```